# Categorial predictors in logistic regression; how to interpret

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

I am performing a logistic regression where the dependent variable and independent variable are both categorial. The independent variables I am using with this model consist of 10 or more classes. How do I interpret the results of a categorial predictor? Example I have a predictor variable with 13 classes of which 5 classes are not significant. Does this mean I remove the variable? If not how so?